# how to make all cells that contain a space " " to be background color black in html

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[image]

how do i make the cells that contain a space or any type of separator to be black?

this is the code that is in my html

```
 <table >

        <thead class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

            <tr *ngFor="let ligne of grilleHaut">

                <td *ngFor="let charac of ligne.tabDesCar">{{charac}}</td>

            </tr>

            
        </thead>

    </table>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try this solution if its work

```
    <thead class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr *ngFor="let ligne of grilleHaut">

            <td *ngFor="let charac of ligne.tabDesCar" style="padding: 0px;">

                <span *ngIf="charac!=''"> {{charac}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="charac==''" style="background-color: black;width: 100%;height: 100%!important;display: table;">N/A</span>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: it almost works it shows a small mark of black but it does not fill the entire cell black

Comment: please try now :<table>

        <thead class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tr *ngFor="let ligne of grilleHaut">

                <td *ngFor="let charac of ligne.tabDesCar" style="padding: 0px;">

                    <span *ngIf="charac!=''"> {{charac}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="charac==''" style="background-color: black;width: 100%;height: 100%!important;display: table;">""</span>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </thead>

    </table>